# htaccess migration issue from Apache to LiteSpeed

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, litespeed

I recently did an URL spring cleanup in the backend and I'm currently struggling with one of the .htaccess redirects.

What I'm trying to redirect is:

```
https://www.example.com/directory/?type=supplier&category=celebrant&sort=latest
```

which should go to:

```
https://www.example.com/suppliers/type/celebrant
```

I've ended up with this regex and tested it on https://technicalseo.com/tools/htaccess/ but for some reason, my LiteSpeed Enterprise server doesn't seem to like it (other regex work).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/directory/$ [C]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type=supplier&category=([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*) [C]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /suppliers/type/%1 [L,QSD,R=301]
```

Any thoughts on why it doesn't work with the enterprise version of LiteSpeed?

**Update:**

I did enable debug logging as [George Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7490533/george-wang) suggested and what I got is:

```
unknown rewrite condition flag while parsing: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/directory/$ [C]
Invalid rewrite condition while parsing: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/directory/$ [C]
unknown rewrite condition flag while parsing: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type=supplier&category=([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*) [C]
Invalid rewrite condition while parsing: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type=supplier&category=([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*) [C]
Ignored due to previous error while parsing: RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /wedding-suppliers/type/%1 [L,QSD,R=301]
```

Pretty vague for me :(

Comment: "I've ended up with this regex and tested it on ..." - fwiw, that testing tool would seem to be _wrong_ in this case.

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/directory/$ [C]
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type=supplier&category=([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*) [C]
> RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /suppliers/type/%1 [L,QSD,R=301]
> ```

You need to remove the `C` (`chain`) flag. This is a `RewriteRule` flag, it doesn't make sense on the `RewriteCond` directive. (The `C` flag chains *rules* together, not directives.)

Apache would break with a 500 Internal Server Error, but I suspect LiteSpeed is probably just failing silently.

`[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*` - this regex/character class is incorrect, since the `-` (hyphen) needs to either be escaped or appear at the start or end of the character class. Otherwise it tries to calculate a range. This can also be simplified using the `\w` (word character) shorthand character class.

You can also remove the first condition and perform the URL-path check in the `RewriteRule` directive instead.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=supplier&category=([\w-]*)
RewriteRule ^directory/$ /suppliers/type/%1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

If LiteSpeed doesn't like the `QSD` flag (new with Apache 2.4) then remove it and append a `?` to the end of the substitution string. ie. `... /suppliers/type/%1? [R=301,L]`

This redirect will need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: As per your instructions, I was able to fix the issue by changing the regex to what MrWhite put together. Thank you

Just to confirm, [QSD] works in LiteSpeed Enterprise but also appending ? after %1 like in your example. And instead of my initial [a-zA-Z0-9-_]* I ended up using [\w'-]* just to include hyphens as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/directory/$ [C]
```

see if it helps or not. If not, you may need to turn on rewrite debug logging to find out what happened.  :-)

Comment: To be honest, that was added by mistake after copy/paste on stackoverflow. The server had the original regex with no "\". Thank you and I will sure try to debug logging the following day.